# A Model to Hold Tags for both Reviews and Threads

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm looking for a way to implement a tag system for Threads and Reviews... I don't know how to go about it.

I want a tag table to holds the name, yet (I think?) I also want the tag table to hold taggable_id which is Threads / Reviews. It's a weird process. Threads can have tags, but so can Reviews, so would it be just a polymorphic Tags table with a pivot polymorphic content_tags table?

I hope everyone can understand what I'm talking about :) Maybe it's a many to many polymorphic tables?

Anyway, thanks in advance for any help.

Would it just be Tag table which can take records, and each time a tag is created a Polymorphic Content_Tag table could contain the tag_id, content_id, and content_type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking on the right lines. Think of tags as a generic entity. A tag can be assigned to anything and anyone, therefore tags are polymorphic as you have pointed out.

Having said that, a typical tag table could look like this.

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->json('name');
            $table->json('slug');
        });
```

The tags table will store the individual tags, think of it like a pool of tags. This would be a great place to ensure tags are unique.

You would then have a taggables table. This table is nothing more than a collection of foreign keys. This is the table that will store the tag against an entity, in your case tags against reviews and threads or anything else you can think of.

A taggables table may look like the following.

```
Schema::create('taggables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
            
            $table->uuid('taggable_id');
            $table->string('taggable_type');

            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

The taggable_id column would be id of the thing you want to tag, e.g. id of a review or a thread.

The taggable_type column would be the class name of the model being tagged e.g. App\Models\Thread or App\Models\Review.

Any model that needs to allow tagging should have a relation with the taggable table that needs to be defined on the model itself perhaps a trait would do the trick.

Finally the tag assignment in your controller or wherever would look something like the following.

```
$review->syncTags(...);
```

**OR**

If you want to save time and don't want to reinvent the wheel, look into Spatie's tags library built for this very purpose [see here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-tags/v2/introduction).

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the following domain:

```
The system has 0..n **threads** 
The system has 0..n **reviews** 
The system has 0..n **tags** 
A thread may have 0..n **tags** 
A review may have 0..n **tags**
```

If that's accurate, the formal relational database design way to do this is to have a joining table from thread to tag, and a separate joining table from review to tag.

In object oriented terms, "thread" and "review" may be subclasses of/implement the interface "taggable". I don't know enough about Laravel to say whether that's a good idea or not; but in general, I prefer not to use inheritance unless there really is an "is a kind of" relationship.